# Adding custom meta data to a table in oracle

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, plsql

I'd like to know if there's a possibility to add some custom metadata to a oracle database table.

The problem at hand is the following:

I'm importing a table from another DB. It might happen that I add additional rows on my side to this table. So far I've written code like

```
    declare
        type coll is table of varchar2(200);
        source_table coll;
        target_table coll;
    begin
        select column_name bulk collect into source_table from all_tab_cols@remdb where table_name='SOURCE_TABLE';
        select column_name bulk collect into target_table from all_tab_cols where table_name='TARGET_TABLE';
        -- is source_table collection a subset of target_table collection?
        if source_table submultiset target_table then
            dbms_output.put_line('source table is a subset of target_table.');
            -- code for this case
        else
            dbms_output.put_line('source table is not a subset of target_table.');
            -- code here for this case
        end if;
    end;
```

This is a elegant solution, but it does not deal with the case that the source_table get's some columns removed. I could of course create a table which could store the number of columns in the source table. I then could check for the number of columns in this table and if it's bigger than the current number of columns then some columns have been removed in the source table.

**BUT** I believe this is not an elegant solution. It adds another table to my Data Warehouse which increases complexity unnecessarily. That's why I wonder if there is a way to add some meta data to the target table itself. I could store the number of cols of the source table there. This would be more elegant, but is it doable?

Or is there another way you can think of?

I suppose it's needless to say, that I begann with oracle very recently.

Comment: (Looks like your last sentence got truncated.) Column comments maybe, but doesn't seem particularly nice.

Comment: Thanks @Mat! I added the missing ending. Yes, I thought about adding it to the comment, but this would be much worse than creating a new table in the DB IMHO.

Comment: Well the even less high-tech way of doing that would be through a column naming convention (prefix or suffix for locally defined ones). I don't know anything else, but your extra table solution sounds cleanest to me anyway.

Comment: @Mat: I was thinking about the prefix/suffix option, too. It would be even possible at this point as the remote DB has the same prefix for all their column names, but we are not responsible for it, meaning it can change anytime.
The columns we might add do each have different prefixes which we use database wide, but I'd need to check for all of those then. Again someone might get the idea of adding a column with a yet different prefix. Right now I also think that a new table would be the cleanest solution, but I'll wait, maybe till monday, maybe someone has another idea. thx